# How to add info to a dialog box that delphi determined

Tags: delphi-2010

I need want to take the info Delphi solved and display the answers in a pop up dialog box

```
procedure TfrmPointsCalculation.btnCalculateClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 rinput: real;
 ipionts: integer;
 bntcalculculate: integer;
begin
 rinput := strtofloat(edtamount.Text);

 ipionts := trunc (rinput/500)*5 ;

 reddisplay.lines.add('Amount Spent' + #9 +floattostrF(rinput,ffcurrency,8,2));

 reddisplay.Lines.add('Pionts Earned' +#9 + inttostr(ipionts));

 bntcalculculate := messagedlg ('',mtConfirmation,
                              [mbOk], 0);
```

What code do I put in the `('')` to show the answers that Delphi found?

Comment: In which variable is the answer that Delphi found? (By the way, Delphi don't find any answer. Delphi generated executable according to your source can do calculation and find an answer to the problem YOU are programming.

Comment: You already know how to build up a string by concatenating substrings, and converting other types to strings. So, what is stopping you from creating the string you want to display?